# Help with editing .bst file to output article titles in the bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I am using this .bst file in my LaTeX document:
 http://ads.harvard.edu/pubs/bibtex/astronat/apj/apj.bst

Everything is working, except that I would like the outputs in the reference section to contain article titles, which they currently do not.

The .bst file allows for each entry to have a title, and all of the ones in my citation file do, but it just doesn't get output in the bibliography.

Is there some modification I can make to the .bst file to get the titles to output to the bibliography?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Make a copy of the `bst` file, calling it (say) `myapj.bst`. Open `myapj.bst` in a text editor, find the function `article` (right after the line `%%%%%%%  End of functions from astrobib`), and insert the instruction `format.title "title" output.check` on a line by itself, *between* the lines that say `date.block` and `crossref missing$`, resp. Save the file, and start using with `\bibliographystyle{myapj}`. The first time you use a new `.bst` file, be sure to latex the main file, bibtex it, and latex it twice more.

Comment: Thanks, Mico! That's got it. Could you point me in the direction of a good reference that has syntax commands for a .bst file, so I could tweak it further if I need to?

Comment: You're welcome. Let me write up my blurb as an official answer. This will also give me space to provide pointers for further forays into bibtex programming.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to edit the `article` function in `apj.bst` and provide an instruction to print the contents of the entry's `title` field. I suggest you do so as follows:

- Make a copy of the file `apj.bst`; call the copy, say, `myapj.bst`.
- Open the file `myapj.bst` in a text editor and search for the function called `article`. I believe it starts right after the line that says `%%%%%%%  End of functions from astrobib`.
- In the function `article`, locate the lines

  ```
    date.block
    crossref missing$
  ```
- Insert the line

  ```
    format.title "title" output.check
  ```

  *between* these two lines.
- Save the file `myapj.bst`, either in the directory where your main `.tex` file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter method, you should also update the TeX distribution's filename database.
- Start using the new bibliography style with the instruction `\bibliographystyle{myapj}`. When switching from one bibliography style to another, it's important to run latex, bibtex, and latex twice more so that all changes are fully propagated.

If you're interested in learning more about the BibTeX infix syntax, I heartily recommend you read the document [Tame the BeaST -- The B to X of BibTeX](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/bibtex/tamethebeast) by Nicolas Markey.