# How do i show article names in my bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am using a template, i am a complete beginner, and i dont know what information i need to provide to get help. My books get a title but my articles dont, what do i need to change?

```
\usepackage{natbib}                   
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{,}
\setcitestyle{square}
\begin{document}

    \bibliographystyle{../references/bibstyle_aa.bst}
    \bibliography{../references/bibfile_thesis.bib}
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This will be set by the bibliography style, so the simple answer is use a different bibliography style that does what you want.  If you really want to mess with the existing `.bst` to make a new one, the only `bibstyle_aa.bst` I can find online is based on `apj.bst` so [this question may help](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165011/106162).

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked.

Comment: If the template is to submit the article to a journal, you should not change the output.